# Thread in Android ---> Unfortunately ThreadApp has Stopped

Tags: android

I have one textview, which i can use to show countdown timer. I wanted to use Thread class which takes Runnable interface.

I wrote the following code for the same but it is gives run time error **Unfortunately ThreadApp has Stopped**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable
{

TextView tvTimer;
Thread timerThread;
int time=30;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvTimer =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    timerThread= new Thread(this);
    timerThread.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        tvTimer.setText((String.valueOf(time)).toString());
        time--;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

At the same time when i removed **tvTimer.setText((String.valueOf(time)).toString());** it works fine. Can anyone provide me the solution. I am new in android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use updating UI using RunOnUiThread like this

```
 @Override
    public void run()
    {
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
              tvTimer.setText((String.valueOf(time)).toString());                       
        }
        });
        time--;
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e)
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }

     }
```

Comment: thread.sleep() is a bad design. check the link here http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: I just want to help the person who posted the code.Therefore I only show the way to prevent the error.Designing is up to you to decide.Hope you got it Raghunandan

Answer (score 2):

> when i removed tvTimer.setText((String.valueOf(time)).toString()); it
>   works fine

because you are trying to change TextView text from non-ui Thread so use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for updating TextView from other Thread

Comment: Can you please give me an example for runOnUIThread or Handler.

Comment: @Raaga : you can see @ Raghunandan answer because he included both example

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx. using thread. sleep() inside a thread is a bad design. Can you shed some light on this.Just for my clarification. I read the same somewhere on SO

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK found the link sorry for disturbing http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update ui in timer task. Timer task runs on a different thread. update ui on the ui thread. Use a handler or runonuithread

```
       Handler m_handler;
       Runnable m_handlerTask ;  
       m_handler = new Handler();
       m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
       {
         @Override 
         public void run() {
            tvTimer.setText((String.valueOf(time)).toString()); 
            timer--;
                   // do something 
              m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000); // instad of 1000 mention the delay in milliseconds
         }
       };
       m_handlerTask.run();
```

Or use

```
@Override
public void run()
{
try
{
    Thread.sleep(1000); 
    // should not call thread.sleep() bad design
    // check the edit below
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

              @Override
              public void run(){
                //update ui here
                 tvTimer.setText((String.valueOf(time)).toString()); 
              }
           });

    time--;
}
catch (InterruptedException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Edit: Using Thread.sleep() inside a thread is a bad design.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Quoting from the docs.

**If you implement Thread or HandlerThread, be sure that your UI thread does not block while waiting for the worker thread to complete—do not call Thread.wait() or Thread.sleep()**. Instead of blocking while waiting for a worker thread to complete, your main thread should provide a Handler for the other threads to post back to upon completion. Designing your application in this way will allow your app's UI thread to remain responsive to input and thus avoid ANR dialogs caused by the 5 second input event timeout.

To stops use this m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);

Comment: Then, How to stop Handler or runOnUiThread. I want to stop it when it reaches to zero and again starts with users event(say when user press  buttonStart which is also the part of layout)

Comment: @Raaga why did you unaceept my answer?

Comment: @Raaga you can check if timer==0 then you can stop the handelr using m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask). also if someone gives a better answer than what i posted you can accept the same. I am not insisting to accept my answer. Just wanted to know the reason

Comment: @Raaga why the unaccept now? i answered before the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {   

@Override
public void run() {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            tvTimer.setText((String.valueOf(time)).toString());
            time--;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update the UI element i.e., a TextView in your thread. You can't do this in a thread. Instead use a handler to post changes to your UI element as follows -

```
   Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        { 
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            handler.post(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    tvTimer.setText((String.valueOf(time)).toString());
                }
            time--;
            });
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
```