# Android wait in UI thread without freezing it

Tags: android, multithreading

In my application when user presses a button MediaRecorder starts recording the audio then it continues recording for 50sec and stops automatically.I am starting the recorder from UI Thread but how to wait for 50s without freezing the UI.Here is my code :

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
recorder.setOutputFile(path);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
Thread.sleep(40000);
recorder.stop();
recorder.reset();
recorder.release();
```

I don't know much about threads.Please help

Comment: use a handler or a timer task. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829374/thread-in-android-unfortunately-threadapp-has-stopped/16829414#16829414. Don't use thread.sleep() check the link @ http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: The basic point is that you don't wait on the ui thread.  Rather, you setup something so that the ui thread will be called again with another event at the desired poing in the future, so that you can quickly return from the current event call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like this, Android provides some tools so you don't need a thread. If you have a handy `View` object (or if this code is in a `View` subclass), you can use [`View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) to schedule a `Runnable` to execute after a specific delay (in milliseconds).

```
// need to make recorder final so it can be referenced from anonymous Runnable
final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
recorder.setOutputFile(path);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();
    }
}, 40000);
```

If you don't have a handy `View`, just create a `Handler` and use it's `postDelayed` method. It works the same.

Comment: @MaciejGórski - Huh? What memory leaks?